# How to backup docker containers, volumes, and images with Bareos?

Tags: docker, bareos

Docker stores its containers, volumes, and images in a collection of large files under `/var` which is not the greatest thing for backing up incrementally.

With Bareos, I understand that [backing up MySQL databases has the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466110/how-can-i-backup-mysql-database-with-bareos) and can be done with bpipe.

How can I backup Docker containers (and images, although there's another solution to that*) so that they are easily able to be restored to the same machine or another one?

*(There's also [docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/), which will let you `push` images to a remote repository, which works a bit like a backup also, but without the backup mindset.  And it only works for images, not containers or volumes.)

Answer (score 1):

For images, one way you can do this is to use the [save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) command offered by Docker. By running:
 `$ docker save --output output_filename.tar your_image`, Docker will save the image you have specified to a tar file within the directory you are currently in. You are then able to save this image, or move it to another machine.

For containers, you can use the [export](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/) command. This will save the contianer's filesystem to a tar file. This is done by running: `docker export --output="output_filename.tar" your_container`.

For using the image, you can use the [load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) command to import the tar file. This can be done by running: `$ docker load --input your_image.tar`.

Comment: Yes, but how does that work with BareOS or Bacula?  They both handle things like incremental and differential backups which obviously would be very resource intensive if we were to `docker save` or `docker export` every time.